# Setting a preference value from stored preference

Tags: iphone, xcode, nsuserdefaults

Playing with my code today,

I run this particular piece of code several times in minor variations throughout a particular class, I'm trying to streamline though. The difference in effect is minimal but changes the amount of code by a volume of hundreds or thousands of lines so would be a big personal win for me.

Essentially I have a value stored as an integer with a key of 'codeKey' and I want to insert the value of that key where the number 30061 currently resides. I'm at a bit of a loss how, can anyone help me out with this one?

I know I need to recall the value somehow and place it in but I'm not really sure how that would look.

```
 if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"buttonID"] == 1) {
        NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [userDefaults setInteger:30061   forKey:@"scifi1"];
        [userDefaults synchronize];}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it you mean dynamically saving this information without duplicating the same code over and over. If that is correct, your solution will be something like this:

```
-(void)saveCodeKey:(int)key {

     if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"buttonID"] == 1) {

        NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [userDefaults setInteger:key   forKey:@"scifi1"];
        [userDefaults synchronize];

    }
}
```

Now you can simply invoke `[self saveCodeKey:12345];` Assuming the `-saveCodeKey:` method resides in the same class.

Hope this helps !

Comment: I think it just might...I need to try it first. I presume in this example 'key' would be what I store the value of 30061 in from my example above e.g. `code`        NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [userDefaults setInteger:30061   forKey:@"key"];
        [userDefaults synchronize];`code`

Comment: I was under the impression the integer value is what need to be changes, not the key itself. If this is the case your parameter needs to be a string and not an int

Comment: Essentially I'll be storing a value somewhere else in Integer form (for various reasons) which needs to be recalled and positioned where you have `code`[userDefaults setInteger:HERE forKey:"@scifi1'];`code` essentially setting a key from a key if that makes sense.

Comment: Just popping back, have put this in my code and (even if we're at cross understandings) it works a charm. Thank you. One green tick, very well deserved.